# Tailwinds UI sidebar component and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-ui

I am new using tailwind ui components

so how to use this and route it.. in other words, how when clicking on left panel link option it changes the right panel by using reactjs.

I would like to see a project example using the tailwind ui code below.

see the tailwind UI sidebar.

Thank in advance for any help on it.

````
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { Dialog, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import {
  BellIcon,
  CalendarIcon,
  ChartBarIcon,
  FolderIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  InboxIcon,
  MenuAlt2Icon,
  UsersIcon,
  XIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import { SearchIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

const navigation = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', href: '#', icon: HomeIcon, current: true },
  { name: 'Team', href: '#', icon: UsersIcon, current: false },
  { name: 'Projects', href: '#', icon: FolderIcon, current: false },
  { name: 'Calendar', href: '#', icon: CalendarIcon, current: false },
  { name: 'Documents', href: '#', icon: InboxIcon, current: false },
  { name: 'Reports', href: '#', icon: ChartBarIcon, current: false },
]
const userNavigation = [
  { name: 'Your Profile', href: '#' },
  { name: 'Settings', href: '#' },
  { name: 'Sign out', href: '#' },
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function Example() {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      {/*
        This example requires updating your template:

        ```
        <html class="h-full bg-gray-100">
        <body class="h-full">
        ```
      */}
      <div>
        <Transition.Root show={sidebarOpen} as={Fragment}>
          <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-40 md:hidden" onClose={setSidebarOpen}>
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0"
              enterTo="opacity-100"
              leave="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-75" />
            </Transition.Child>

            <div className="fixed inset-0 flex z-40">
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform"
                enterFrom="-translate-x-full"
                enterTo="translate-x-0"
                leave="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform"
                leaveFrom="translate-x-0"
                leaveTo="-translate-x-full"
              >
                <Dialog.Panel className="relative flex-1 flex flex-col max-w-xs w-full pt-5 pb-4 bg-gray-800">
                  <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-in-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="ease-in-out duration-300"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                  >
                    <div className="absolute top-0 right-0 -mr-12 pt-2">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="ml-1 flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white"
                        onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(false)}
                      >
                        <span className="sr-only">Close sidebar</span>
                        <XIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-white" aria-hidden="true" />
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </Transition.Child>
                  <div className="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center px-4">
                    <img
                      className="h-8 w-auto"
                      src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-indigo-500-mark-white-text.svg"
                      alt="Workflow"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mt-5 flex-1 h-0 overflow-y-auto">
                    <nav className="px-2 space-y-1">
                      {navigation.map((item) => (
                        <a
                          key={item.name}
                          href={item.href}
                          className={classNames(
                            item.current
                              ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white'
                              : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                            'group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium rounded-md'
                          )}
                        >
                          <item.icon
                            className={classNames(
                              item.current ? 'text-gray-300' : 'text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300',
                              'mr-4 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6'
                            )}
                            aria-hidden="true"
                          />
                          {item.name}
                        </a>
                      ))}
                    </nav>
                  </div>
                </Dialog.Panel>
              </Transition.Child>
              <div className="flex-shrink-0 w-14" aria-hidden="true">
                {/* Dummy element to force sidebar to shrink to fit close icon */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </Dialog>
        </Transition.Root>

        {/* Static sidebar for desktop */}
        <div className="hidden md:flex md:w-64 md:flex-col md:fixed md:inset-y-0">
          {/* Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like */}
          <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col min-h-0 bg-gray-800">
            <div className="flex items-center h-16 flex-shrink-0 px-4 bg-gray-900">
              <img
                className="h-8 w-auto"
                src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-indigo-500-mark-white-text.svg"
                alt="Workflow"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col overflow-y-auto">
              <nav className="flex-1 px-2 py-4 space-y-1">
                {navigation.map((item) => (
                  <a
                    key={item.name}
                    href={item.href}
                    className={classNames(
                      item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                      'group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md'
                    )}
                  >
                    <item.icon
                      className={classNames(
                        item.current ? 'text-gray-300' : 'text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300',
                        'mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6'
                      )}
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                ))}
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="md:pl-64 flex flex-col">
          <div className="sticky top-0 z-10 flex-shrink-0 flex h-16 bg-white shadow">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="px-4 border-r border-gray-200 text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500 md:hidden"
              onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(true)}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
              <MenuAlt2Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
            </button>
            <div className="flex-1 px-4 flex justify-between">
              <div className="flex-1 flex">
                <form className="w-full flex md:ml-0" action="#" method="GET">
                  <label htmlFor="search-field" className="sr-only">
                    Search
                  </label>
                  <div className="relative w-full text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-600">
                    <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                      <SearchIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </div>
                    <input
                      id="search-field"
                      className="block w-full h-full pl-8 pr-3 py-2 border-transparent text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:placeholder-gray-400 focus:ring-0 focus:border-transparent sm:text-sm"
                      placeholder="Search"
                      type="search"
                      name="search"
                    />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div className="ml-4 flex items-center md:ml-6">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="bg-white p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                  <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>

                {/* Profile dropdown */}
                <Menu as="div" className="ml-3 relative">
                  <div>
                    <Menu.Button className="max-w-xs bg-white flex items-center text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                      <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                      <img
                        className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                        alt=""
                      />
                    </Menu.Button>
                  </div>
                  <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                    enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                    leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                  >
                    <Menu.Items className="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                      {userNavigation.map((item) => (
                        <Menu.Item key={item.name}>
                          {({ active }) => (
                            <a
                              href={item.href}
                              className={classNames(
                                active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '',
                                'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700'
                              )}
                            >
                              {item.name}
                            </a>
                          )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                      ))}
                    </Menu.Items>
                  </Transition>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <main className="flex-1">
            <div className="py-6">
              <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
                <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900">Dashboard</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
                {/* Replace with your content */}
                <div className="py-4">
                  <div className="border-4 border-dashed border-gray-200 rounded-lg h-96" />
                </div>
                {/* /End replace */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
````

Comment: What have you tried so far? The code looks like there isn't any action on navigation items.

Comment: As I said I new with it... correct ...I just copied the code from tailwinds ui... what I would like to know is how to include the navigation action on  ..  when clicking the link on left panel and load the corresponding "page" component in the right panel.  thanks